# In mongodb, how to query whether the array element in the sub object is greater than 0 and delete it

Tags: mongodb

the mongodb document like this

```
"id":"606d254328f299fe4cad236f",
"propInfo":{
    "aaa":{
        "a":[
            {"time":0, "count":1},
        ],
        "b":[
            {"time":50, "count":1},
            {"time":6, "count":1},
            {"time":57, "count":1},
            {"time":87, "count":1},
            {"time":777, "count":1},
            {"time":12, "count":1},
            {"time":11, "count":1}
        ]
    },
    "bbb":{
        "aa":[
            {"time":0, "count":1},
        ],
        "bb":[
            {"time":2, "count":1},
            {"time":1, "count":1},
            {"time":88, "count":1},
            {"time":5, "count":1},
            {"time":66, "count":1},
            {"time":65, "count":1},
            {"time":8, "count":1}
        ]
    }
}
```

how to query whether the array element in the sub object is greater than 10

```
('propInfo.*.*.$[].time > 10')
```

and remove all qualified
{"time":xx, "count":xx}

Comment: What is "greater than 10"? The number of elements? What is "the sub object"? What do you mean by "delete it"? Delete the document, the entire array or just single elements from that array? Do you like to query the result or update existing data?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  
"greater than 10" is 'time' field in array. Just single elements from that array and update existing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple static solution is this one:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
   [
      {
         $set: {
            propInfo: {
               aaa: {
                  a: { $filter: { input: "$propInfo.aaa.a", cond: { $lte: ["$$this.time", 10] } } },
                  b: { $filter: { input: "$propInfo.aaa.b", cond: { $lte: ["$$this.time", 10] } } }
               },
               bbb: {
                  aa: { $filter: { input: "$propInfo.bbb.aa", cond: { $lte: ["$$this.time", 10] } } },
                  bb: { $filter: { input: "$propInfo.bbb.bb", cond: { $lte: ["$$this.time", 10] } } }
               },
            }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

However, if you need dynamic (i.e. arbitrary) field names, then it will be more complex. A generic solution would be this one:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
   [
      // Transform first level
      { $set: { propInfo: { $objectToArray: "$propInfo" } } },
      // Transform second level
      {
         $set: {
            propInfo: {
               $map: {
                  input: "$propInfo",
                  in: { k: "$$this.k", v: { $objectToArray: "$$this.v" } }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      // Filter "time <= 10"
      {
         $set: {
            propInfo: {
               $map: {
                  input: "$propInfo",
                  as: "top",
                  in: {
                     k: "$$top.k",
                     v: {
                        $map: {
                           input: "$$top.v",
                           in: {
                              k: "$$this.k",
                              v: { $filter: { input: "$$this.v", as: "v", cond: { $lte: ["$$v.time", 10] } } }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      // Revert second level transformation
      {
         $set: {
            propInfo: {
               $map: {
                  input: "$propInfo",
                  in: { k: "$$this.k", v: { $arrayToObject: "$$this.v" } }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      // Revert first level transformation
      { $set: { propInfo: { $arrayToObject: "$propInfo" } } }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  This method is very helpful to me!